# Attribute Modifications in Graphical Interface in Java SVG

Tags: java, svg, batik

I want to render java objects in some graphical format with the domain specific icons/terminology.

2 most important feature i would like in this graphics mode are
1) Ability to change an attribute of the image by selecting it with mouse
2) Ability to zoom in/out on section of the image.

Can I use Apache Batik to render the graphics in SVG. And can it provide me with the above mentioned functionality.

Please feel free to suggest me any other java based framework/technology which can help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible with Batik. But I can not recommend to use batik. It seems to be dead (has not been updated since January 2008), has some heavy performance issues when using animated svg's and has many bugs. But if you want to use it for a home-made project, that doesn't need to be totally stable, its ok.

The [JSVGCanvas](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/swing/JSVGCanvas.html) displays an svg-file and you can pan, zoom and rotate it. You're also be able to install listeners to interact with elements.